# ParserError: Expected ';' but got ',' --> votingplatform.sol:38:37: | 38 | require(voters[voter].voted), "The voter already voted"); | ^

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I'm currently working with the solidity documentation and I keep getting this error:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got ','
--> votingplatform.sol:38:37:
|
38 | require(voters[voter].voted), "The voter already voted");
| ^
[//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

contract Ballot {
/*This contract is going to allow for delegation, which  basically means that as a voter
you can delegate or give your vote away to someone else  */

```
struct Voter {
    uint weight;/*weight is accumulated by delegation. Basically,this is how many votes that a person has
    and when we initialize we are going to give them an initial weight and if another person gives their weight to
    this person, the weight will go up.*/
    bool voted; /*This checked if they have voted or not*/
    address delegate; //person delegated to
    uint vote; //index of the voted proposal, the index of the thing that I'm voting for
}

//This is a type for a single proposal.
struct Proposal {
    bytes32 names;
    uint voteCount;
}
address public chairperson;

mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
Proposal[] public proposals;

constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames){
    chairperson = msg.sender;

    voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
    for(uint i = 0; i > proposalNames.length; i++){
        proposals.push(Proposal({name:proposalNames[i], voteCount: 0}));
    }
}

function giveRightToVote(address voter) external {
    require(msg.sender == chairperson, "Only chairperson can give right to vote.");
    require(!voters[voter].voted), "The voter already voted");
    require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
    voters[voter].weight = 1;
}

function delegate(address to) external { 
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require (sender.weight != 0, "You have no right to vote");
    require(!sender.voted, "You already voted");
    require(to != msg.sender, "Self-Delegation is not allowed");
    
    while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)){
        to = voters[to].delegate;
        require(to != msg.sender, "Found Loop in Delegation.");
    }/* This while loop isnt looping over an array, we just wanna make sure that the address we are
    delegating to is not an empty address, if their address is empty, we can delegate the vote to them, but
    if the address is not empty that means they have already delegated their vote to someone else, so we need to 
    go ahead and reassign the person we want to delegte our vote to to the person whom they delegated their vote to
    */

    sender.voted = true;
    sender.delegate = to;
    Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
    if(delegate_.voted){
        proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }else{
        delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
    }
}
function vote(uint proposal) external {
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote!");
    require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
    sender.voted = true;
    sender.vote = proposal;
    proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
}
function winningProposal() public view returns (uint winningProposal_){
    uint winningVoteCount = 0;
    for (uint p = 0; p < proposal.length; p++) {
        if (proposals[p].votecount > winningVoteCount){
        winningVoteCount = proposal[p].voteCount;
        winningProposal_ = p;
        }
    }
}
function winnerName() external view returns (bytes32 winnerName_){
    winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
}
```

} ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3arGX.png)

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your smart contract. In details, your error is related to this line:

```
require(!voters[voter].voted), "The voter already voted");
```

You must change it with:

```
require(!voters[voter].voted, "The voter already voted");
```

I adjusted your original smart contract in this way (fixing some errors):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

contract Ballot { /*This contract is going to allow for delegation, which basically means that as a voter you can delegate or give your vote away to someone else */

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;/*weight is accumulated by delegation. Basically,this is how many votes that a person has
        and when we initialize we are going to give them an initial weight and if another person gives their weight to
        this person, the weight will go up.*/
        bool voted; /*This checked if they have voted or not*/
        address delegate; //person delegated to
        uint vote; //index of the voted proposal, the index of the thing that I'm voting for
    }

    //This is a type for a single proposal.
    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 names;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address public chairperson;

    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
    Proposal[] public proposals;

    constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) {
        chairperson = msg.sender;

        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
        for(uint i = 0; i > proposalNames.length; i++){
            proposals.push(Proposal({names:proposalNames[i], voteCount: 0}));
        }
    }

    function giveRightToVote(address voter) external {
        require(msg.sender == chairperson, "Only chairperson can give right to vote.");
        require(!voters[voter].voted, "The voter already voted");
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }

    function delegate(address to) external { 
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require (sender.weight != 0, "You have no right to vote");
        require(!sender.voted, "You already voted");
        require(to != msg.sender, "Self-Delegation is not allowed");
        
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)){
            to = voters[to].delegate;
            require(to != msg.sender, "Found Loop in Delegation.");
        }
        /* This while loop isnt looping over an array, we just wanna make sure that the address we are
        delegating to is not an empty address, if their address is empty, we can delegate the vote to them, but
        if the address is not empty that means they have already delegated their vote to someone else, so we need to 
        go ahead and reassign the person we want to delegte our vote to to the person whom they delegated their vote to
        */
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
        if(delegate_.voted){
            proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        }else{
            delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
        }
    }

    function vote(uint proposal) external {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote!");
        require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposal;
        proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public view returns (uint winningProposal_){
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount){
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposal_ = p;
            }
        }
    }

    function winnerName() external view returns (bytes32 winnerName_){
        winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your giveRight to function , you mistakenly added another paranthesis in the below require condition

```
require(!voters[voter].voted), "The voter already voted");
```